# Console logging object values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, template-literals

As part of a bootcamp I am taking, I have been asked to create an online shopping cart. 
I am having such a problem with the addToCart function in the sense that I keep managing to to console log [{itemName: item, itemPrice: 8}] rather than 'item has been added to cart.

I think my problem lies in my template literal.

The aim is for the function to take in an item, create an object around it, apply additional properties, add to the cart array, console log that the item has been added (this is where my problem lies) then return the cart.

I have tried a number of alternatives such as trying to access the values via dot notation and using the key of the object to access the value. still have had no joy.

Below is my code:

```
function addToCart(item) {
  // write your code here
  var price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  var obj = {itemName: item, itemPrice: price};
  cart.push(obj);
  console.log(`${item} has been added to your cart.`)
  return cart;
}
```

What I am expecting is for the item that is being parsed into the function to be log to the console stating that the item has been added. I believe the rest of the code is working fine as it is passing the local tests.

The error I get is this:

Error: Expected [{itemName:'ice cream', itemPrice: 26}] to equal 'ice cream has been added to your cart.'

Any tips would be very helpful.

Comment: What do you want to see logged in the console?

Comment: How are you calling your function "addToCart" ?

Comment: Could you please add your UTC (test code) also..  may be problem lies there

Comment: `console.log(`${item.itemName} has been added to your cart.`)}`

This is not working?

Comment: @RafaelDuarte thank you for taking the time to help. I am expecting to see is the item name of the object to be console logged as part of a template literal. For instance, if I passed in Ice cream, I am expecting the console log output to display 'ice cream has been added to your cart'.

Comment: @Jayd Robinson , as Tudor said, the error you're getting is most likely coming from a test, do you have any tests running?

Comment: @niranjanharpale from what i can gather looking at the addToCart () looks as though its being called in a usual manner in the test.     code snippet below:                                                       describe("addToCart()", function() {
  it("can add items to the cart", function() {
    addToCart("apples");

    expect(getCart().length).toEqual(1);

    addToCart("bananas");

    expect(getCart().length).toEqual(2);

Comment: @RafaelDuarte the test code can be found here https://github.com/JaydR119/js-basics-online-shopping-lab-bootcamp-prep-000/blob/master/test/index-test.js

Comment: @niranjanharpale test code can be found here https://github.com/JaydR119/js-basics-online-shopping-lab-bootcamp-prep-000/blob/master/test/index-test.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at your tests,

Try following

your test is (I hope I picked the right one) :

```
it("returns a message indicating that the item has been added", function() {
    expect(addToCart("ice cream")).toEqual("ice cream has been added to your cart.");

    expect(addToCart("juice")).toEqual("juice has been added to your cart.");
  });
```

Change your code to :

```
function addToCart(item) {
  // write your code here
  var price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  var obj = {itemName: item, itemPrice: price};
  cart.push(obj);
  console.log(`${item} has been added to your cart.`)
  return `${item} has been added to your cart.`;
  //OR
  //return `${obj.itemName} has been added to your cart.`;
}
```

As you are comparing the returned value from "addToCart" in your test with the string in .toEqual so, so you should return that particular formatted string from your function.

So instead of returning **cart**, you should return that *particular string* that you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the cart as a global variable. Please check the below code snippet.

```js
cart = [];

(function() {
   addToCart("Apple");
   addToCart("Orange");
   
   console.log(this.cart)
})();

function addToCart(item) {
  var price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  var obj = {itemName: item, itemPrice: price};
  this.cart.push(obj);
  console.log(`${item} has been added to your cart.`)
  return cart;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Googlian, I will try this

Comment: I can confirm that I needed to return the string that was needed rather than console log it. the questions sometimes in the bootcamp i am taking are very open ended. I have found a solution that has worked though.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error you're getting makes me think **the error is thrown by a test** you're running.

That test is checking **the value returned by your function** and not what's logged in the console. In order to not get the error anymore, you should fix that test.

Assuming your tests are using Jasmine, that test would look something like:

```
const cart = addToCart(item);
expect( cart[0]['itemName'] ).toBe('ice cream')
```

Comment: Thank you Tudor I will check this.